# WiFi doesn't work on my Macbook Air 1.1

Tags: wireless, macbook-air

I just downloaded the newest Ubuntu 14.10 to my Macbook Air 1.1 (2008). Otherwise it is working perfectly but the WiFi is not working. I guess there is a problem with the driver? It has Broadcom BCM4321 inside of it. Could you give me hint what should I write to the Terminal to get it working? Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package?

Comment: I downloaded the bcmwl-kernel-source and firmware-b43-installer to my USB drive and installed them in terminal. I can see from software center that those are installed but Wifi is not still working.

Comment: Yes,  bcmwl-kernel-source package appears to be Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source. By the way PCI.ID 14e4:4328. I have reboot several times after the installation but it still says that "No network devices available" @Robith Madhavan

Comment: Do you have the package `dkms` installed? It is a dependency for `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: dkms is also installed. Actually I had not installed firmware-b43-installer. Right now I am trying to install it but it requires to "release amd64 (20141022.1)'". It asks me to insert the download cd which I apparently dont have because I downloaded the operating system to USB flash drive. @Rohith Madhavan

Comment: Did the WiFi work in live media?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The solution is

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

if it is installed and instead

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Also need to put in the module *b43* in the `/etc/modules` files to autoload it at bootup.